# Use GitHub Actions and Helm to deploy to AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, github-actions, azure-aks

I have setup an Azure Kubernetes Service and manually successfully deployed multiple *Helm charts*.

I now want to setup up a CD pipeline using GitHub Actions and *Helm* to deploy (that is install and upgrade) a Helm chart whenever the Action is triggers.

Up until now I only found Actions that use *kubectl* for deployment, which I don't want to use, because there are some secrets provided in the manifests that I don't want to check into version control, hence the decision for *Helm* as it can fill these secrets with values provided as environmental variables when running the helm install command:

```
# without Helm
...
clientId: secretValue

# with Helm
...
clientId: {{ .Values.clientId }}
```

The "secret" would be provided like this: *helm install --set clientId=secretValue*.

Now the question is how can I achieve this using GitHub Actions? Are there any "ready-to-use" solutions available that I just haven't found or do I have to approach this in a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I made things more complicated than I needed.

I ended up with writing a simple GitHub Action based on the *alpine/helm* docker image and was able to successfully setup the CD pipeline into AKS.

Comment: Could you share it?